# GridView and DataGrid column DataSource extra column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to use Data Grid and Grid View

`<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrdBuilding" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Building Name" DataField="Building"></asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>`

as it shows extra column from **DataSource** here is the code

```
DataGrdBuilding.DataSource = (from k in en.ClientSiteBuildings
                                      where k.ClientSiteId == _ClientSiteId
                                      select new { Building = k.ClientSiteBuildingName }).ToList();
            DataGrdBuilding.DataBind();
```

If i use any of the above it will show extra column.

Here is the image below.
[image: Extra Column]

Answer (score 1):

use, `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`

[MSD Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8)